# Xcode error : Abort trap 6 (only show in device)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

it's very strange , my project is all right until I open my Xcode this morning , I did not change any thing but I got an `Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6` ( I user Xcode9 and Swift4). but with simulations, everything works fine.[image]

I have tried turn swift optimization to [No] but don't work.

Comment: Xcode doesn’t lie. ;) There should be something changed.

Comment: maybe...but I tried roll back.and I'm quite sure there is no such error at that version

Comment: Why don't you create a new project and move your files into it and build it? Other people did like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try out doing one thing if you are using pods

```
Step 1 - Make a copy of your project
```

here try 2 different things

```
Step 2 - Pod update
```

if this did not work then

```
Step 2 - Run pod deintegrate

Step 3 - pod install
```

Just try if it helps

Comment: Sometime it happenes even sometime cleaning too works

Comment: well, after i do some change of my code. the error shows again. I tired pod deintegrate and pod install . and so far, the abort trap error not show on again. thanks. and how did you know it's about the pod problem? I can't inter it just from the error message.

Comment: as you mentioned everything works fine with simulation, So from here I got its going to be pod issue , as when we compile on device that Time you might be getting such issue so while we compile two things to be compiled your code and your pods , if code has no issue then pods may have so I wrote these steps

Comment: thanks, and I found it's may be about the swift4 update problem. my project is original written by objective-c language . and then i mixed with swift3.2 , recently I updated my Xcode to 9.1 and swift4. then I found Xcode recommend me to "update to recommended settings"(Pod project & myProject) after I do as Xcode told me .the error shows on. and after I reinstall all my pod lib. the "update to recommended settings" tips shows again.

Comment: i had a similar issue and the only way i was able to resolve it was removing the workspace's DerivedData

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error because you updated your Xcode to version 13.3 and it's happening because of file_picker (Flutter) then check this on https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/999

I added this to my iOs project's podfile inside the target 'Runner' do :

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'
end
```

And now I can archive successfully pending on when the author will push the next update on pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Abort Trap (In my case my code is working perfectly but when I trying to make an Archive for upload app on testFlight file I got the "Abort Trap")

Solution:- Just Select Your Project from project Navegater (most Left Pane)  Select Project > Select Targets > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Genration > Optimization Level > Debug and Realease make "No Optimization [-Onone]"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH1Yb.jpg)